# Retrofit 2: upload image to server and get strange response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I used Retrofit version 2.0.1 for uploading image from my Android phone to server and I got a strange error.
This is my API interface for Post to server:

```
@POST("/vistek/myservice.php")
    Call<String> send(@Part("myFile") RequestBody file);
```

My Okttp client is:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor2 = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
  interceptor2.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
  interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

  httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
  httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor2);
```

And my function for sending image to server:

```
public void sendImage(byte[] data)
    {
        MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
        FileUploadService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, data);

        Call<String> call = service.send(requestBody);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response) {
                Log.d("Upload", "success = " + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d("Upload","failure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

After call function, I got strange response, something like this:

������JFIF����������������C������C�������"��������������������������
04-12 17:30:11.144 11669-13785/mmlab.visualsearch D/OkHttp: �����������}��!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
04-12 17:30:11.144 11669-13785/mmlab.visualsearch D/OkHttp: %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
04-12 17:30:11.144 11669-13785/mmlab.visualsearch D/OkHttp: ���������w��!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br�

My server works normally when I test api with Postman:

```
POST /vistek/myservice.php HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.mmlab.uit.edu.vn
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ba965fb1-f7b9-7344-8b8a-ab46095668d1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename=""
Content-Type: 

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Please help me to know what happen with my code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **NOT** strange response. It is compressed (gzip).

It seems like you have added `"accept-encoding", "gzip"` in `header` to your request. In that case, it's your responsibility to unzip the response.

So what you can do is:

Just omit the `accept-encoding` header from your code. `OkHttp` will add its own `accept-encoding` header, and if the server responds with gzip then OkHttp will silently unzip it for you.

You can also manually decompress it like this:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body().getBytes());
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

String readed;
while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(readed);
}
in.close();
reader.close();
gzis.close();
String unZippedResponse = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: My request does not include "accept-encoding", "gzip" in header

Comment: Can you post how you are creating `OkHttp` client and are you using any interceptors?

Comment: My OkHttp client is: 
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor2 = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor2.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor2);

Comment: can you post `OkHttp` Client creation and all `interceptors` in question. So that readability is better.

Comment: @KanzakiNguyen, also your Api interface.

Comment: Please check the API interface in head part of my question

Comment: I cannot get response body because the callback onFailure() is called. The result I wrote in my question is from Log Monitor

Comment: Gson cannot parse the response because the response is strange, so callback onFailure() is called. I think so.

Comment: no, that's not the case I think. Anyway what response are you expecting? Cam you post that

Comment: I want to get response is a url: http://smart.citynow.jp/getimage/uploads/Screen_Shot_2016-04-12_at_3.38.42_PM.png

Comment: Sorry to bother you. My code has a mistake when I setting for name of parameter. Now, I can get response perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @KanzakiNguyen, great.. can you also accept my answer. :)